# Proper way to retrieve sequence int after entity save with hibernate and postgresql?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, orm

This is how I'm getting the id from save(entity) method:

```
Serializable save = hibernateTemplate.save(article);
return Integer.valueOf(save.toString());
```

Being a complete noob to hibernate, I just wonder if this is the proper way to do it?
I'll appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is unnecessary to use `Integer.valueOf(save.toString);` because you know type of your identifier and Hibernate of course too. You can use `(Integer)save`.